# Как добавить динамический поиск вводимой информации

Tags: java, android

Добавил в свой макет данный код, теперь не могу понять как добавить поиск по тексту который ввел пользователь. В интернете везде пользуются обычными виджетами SearchView. Почему нигде нет информации по виджетам Matrial Design 3 ?

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/listText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/searchbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <com.google.android.material.search.SearchBar
            android:id="@+id/search_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Нажмите для поиска" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.search.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="Введите текст поиска"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/search_bar">
        <!-- Search suggestions/results go here (ScrollView, RecyclerView, etc.). -->
    </com.google.android.material.search.SearchView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Думаю с помощью этого кода это как то делается ?

```
binding.searchView.addTransitionListener(
            (searchView, previousState, newState) -> {
                if (newState == SearchView.TransitionState.SHOWING) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: Не вполне понятно в чём у вас проблема. Виджет поиска и сам поиск - практически несвязанные вещи. Поиск это, упрощённо, функция, принимающая строку на вход и выдающая результат. Строку на вход функции можно да, из поля ввода взять, например из SearchView. Попробуйте подробно описать с чем именно у вас проблема - с виджетом для ввода текста или с функцией поиска. Или, может, вы затрудняетесь в том, как их объеденить?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Проблема с функцией поиска и объединением функции с виджетом.

Comment: Объединение простое - найдите колбэк, который вызывается по мере ввода текста в виджет. С функцией сложнее - надо знать что вы и где искать хотите. Если вхождение подстроки в строке - то это  одну строку. Если смысл в введённом тексте - нужен кластер серверов и навороченные нейронки.